# How to play an audio with a certain name

Tags: c++

I want to play an audio file with a certain name, for example if the user inputs number 3, i want the code to play the audio file with the name 3.wav.

```
           string a;
           cin >> a;
           PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/" && a && ".wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
```

This of course did not work. Any suggestions? Or do I have to write multiple IFs?

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't have any notion about playing audio files.

Comment: The `&&` operator is not string concatenation in C++. You most likely mean `+`, instead.

Comment: Kristaps, did the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` is a `std::string` (and not a `std::wstring`) you should probably use the ANSI API in Windows (`PlaySoundA`).

You can do it like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a;

    if(std::getline(std::cin, a)) { // getline lets you enter filenames containing spaces
        PlaySoundA(("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/" + a + ".wav").c_str(), nullptr, SND_SYNC);
    }
}
```

Here, `"C:/Users/Name/Desktop/"` and the contents of `a` is concatenated to form a temporary `std::string` and then `".wav"` is concatenated to that string. Finally, the `std::string` member function `c_str()` is called to return a `const char*` which is what `PlaySoundA` expects.

It's probably clearer to create a temporary string first and you could also add a check to see if `PlaySoundA` was successful:

```
int main() {
    std::string a;

    if(std::getline(std::cin, a)) {
        std::string wavpath = "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/" + a + ".wav";
        std::cout << "Playing " << wavpath << '\n';

        if(PlaySoundA(wavpath.c_str(), nullptr, SND_SYNC) == FALSE) {
            std::cout << "Failed playing sound\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Concatenate `std::string`s with `+`, not `&&`. Note this only works with `std::string`s. If you attempt to concatenate character arrays with +, the program will perform pointer arithmetic instead.
2. If you are using Window's wide character API, you need wide characters throughout. THis means you use `std::wstring`, `std::wcin` and use `L` prefix to specify wide character string literals.
3. Avoid using `TEXT` macro. `TEXT` was a quick way to easily port programs from the early Windows OSes that used 8 bit characters to the Windows NT-based OSes that preferred wide characters to make internationalization easier. `TEXT` is used at **compile time** to convert `char` string literals into `wchar` string literals by prepending the `L` prefix if the UNICODE flag is set. Windows XP wiped out all of the older Windows Oses in the early 2000s and since then it's been better to use wide characters through out.

```cpp
std::wstring a; 
//   ^ everything needs to be wide characters
std::wcin >> a; 
//   ^ Even cin
PlaySoundW((L"C:/Users/Name/Desktop/" + a + L".wav").c_str(), NULL, SND_SYNC);
//       ^ zero ambiguity. wide characters only.
//                                                  ^ get wchar array from wstring
//         ^                               ^ wide string literals
```